# How to remove dynamic titles from Durandal HTML StarterKit?

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am testing the single page framework Durandal and I am wondering
how I can change the dynamic html title within the Durandal HTML StarterKit?
First there is a splash screen that has a standard title, e.g. Title1.
After the splash screen there are two default navigation elements: Welcome and Flickr.
If I click on any of those two navigation elements I am getting redirected
to its page content but the html title also changes.
The title then says: "Welcome | Title1" or "Flickr | Title1"
I just want the title to be "Title1" in any case.
How do I go for it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

1) Move into the following directory: "./lib/durandal/js/plugins/"
2) Open the following file in an editor: "router.js"
3) Find the method: "router.updateDocumentTitle = function (instance, instruction) {" and change it like this

```
router.updateDocumentTitle = function (instance, instruction) {
    var appTitle = ko.unwrap(app.title),
        //title = instruction.config.title;
        title = null;

    ....
}
```